# How to create Exchange server rules for all users?

Tags: email, exchange, rules, exchange-2010

How to create Exchange server rules for all users? We want to give each user a rule where "email sent to this distribution group be placed in a special folder". Is this possible? We are using exchange 2010

Answer (score 1):

Check out the New-InboxRule cmdlet in the Exchange Management Shell: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335170(v=exchg.141).aspx